# Azure Active Directory adal4j authentication not returning group membership (any more)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an Azure Active Directory instance which contains my users (along with their passwords) and the roles those users have (as membership of groups).

I use the adal4j AuthenticationContext aquireToken method to get an AuthenticationResult and on that I call getAccessToken to get the string access token.

My app is registered with AD. As part of setting up the app, I changed the AD configuration manifest to include group membership information in the granted access token by adding:

```
"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup",
```

This has been working well for weeks, with a users group membership being included in the access token.

As of this morning, the group membership information is no longer being returned in the access token (which means my application is broken). I haven't changed the code or the AD config, so I have no idea why group membership information is no longer being returned.

I have a couple of questions:

1) Is anyone else experiencing the same problem?

2) Any ideas on what I can do to get Azure Active Directory to include group membership information in the generated access tokens once again?

Thanks, Andy

Comment: Did you get it working? I'm getting our admin to upload an updated manifest simply because I'm presently stymied trying to get membership queried.